# Python to java conversion

Tags: java, python-3.x

I have my original python script as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import math,sys
import json
import urllib

def gsearch(searchfor):
  query = urllib.urlencode({'q': searchfor})
  url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' % query
  search_response = urllib.urlopen(url)
  search_results = search_response.read()
  results = json.loads(search_results)
  data = results['responseData']
  return data

args = sys.argv[1:]
m = 45000000000
if len(args) != 2:
        print "need two words as arguments"
        exit
n0 = int(gsearch(args[0])['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
n1 = int(gsearch(args[1])['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
n2 = int(gsearch(args[0]+" "+args[1])['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
```

I am in the midst of converting it into java. I have done all the following. I am stuck here search_results = search_response.read()  results = json.loads(search_results)       data = results['responseData'] . I dont know how to convert these 3 lines into java.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class gi {

   public static void main (String[] args) {

     if(args.length==2){

         for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("I IS : "+i+":"+args[i]);
            }
         int n0 = searchGoogle(args[0]);
         int n1 = searchGoogle(args[1]);
         int n2 = searchGoogle(args[0]+" "+args[1]);
     }
     else{
        System.out.println("Not enough arguement");
     }
   }
   public static int searchGoogle(String searchQuery)
   {
    try{

    String query=URLEncoder.encode(searchQuery, "UTF-8");
    String url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s" + query;
    URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
    int pageQty=0;
    return pageQty;
   }

}  // end of ReadString class
```

Comment: Can you try using jython to run your python code instead of converting it into java?

Comment: I never come accross jyhton? The problem I need to feed this later into other java application that is the reason I am converting and stuck at these 3 lines

Comment: If you want to run python code from a java environment for interoperability with java you can use jython. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to make this work using something like the following (this is from [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977221/open-url-in-java-to-get-the-content)).

```
String a = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s";
url = new URL(a);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

---

Once you have the `BufferedReader` from the `URLConnection`, you can [get a String object from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666748/java-how-to-read-bufferedreader-faster):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String aux = "";

while ((aux = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(aux);
}

String text = builder.toString();
```

---

Once you have the String object, you can pass that into your JSONObject constructor. (from [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java)).

Using `org.json` library:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(text);
```

---

Now that you have your JSONObject, you can use the available methods to extract the data that you need.

Ex:

```
JSONObject cursorObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("cursor");
int resultCount = cursorObj.getInt("resultCount");
```

Comment: I added this URLConnection connection1 = new URL(url).openConnection();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection1.getInputStream()));
but what should I sent into the JSONOBJECt ?

Comment: Ok I can get the results ready and my only challenge left now is to look for "cursor":{"resultCount":"58,800,000"," and finally get the resultCount value.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a way to get a string from the BufferedReader from the URLConnection. You may have to format the string before passing it into the JSONObject constructor.

Comment: Yes I have followed your way and managed to get the text and the content in text partly is this "cursor":{"resultCount":"58,800,000"," and my final target it to extract the numeric value of resultCount

Comment: For an example on extracting data from your JSON object, check our this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918861/how-to-get-data-from-json-object

Comment: I am a bit stucked here JSONArray data = jsonResult.getJSONArray("responseData");
  if(data != null) {
      String[] cursors = new String[data.length()];
       for(int i = 0 ; i < data.length() ; i++) {
          cursors[i] = data.getString("cursor");
          System.out.println("Curros : "+cursors[i]);
         
      }
  }  I get this error error: method getString in class JSONArray cannot be applied to given types;
                        cursors[i] = data.getString("cursor");

Comment: It looks like that method accepts an integer index parameter, not a string. (see http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#getString(int) )

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it answered your question.